# Unable to copy symbols from this device. Using iOS 9.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

> This device has a version of iOS different from that of this
>   installation of Xcode. In order to copy the information needed to work
>   with this device, Xcode must be run by a user with read/write access
>   to:
>
> "/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/9.0.2
>   (13A452)/Symbols//System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv7s"

Has anyone figured out how to solve this issue? I am trying to set up an iPhone 6s with Xcode, and this just started happening. I tried reinstalling Xcode, but that did nothing.

Edit: Tested my new phone on another computer; it did the same thing. That means it is something with my phone that is causing the problem.

Comment: For people looking at this error who are on iOS < 9, and also don't have an Apple Developer Account, the reason for the error is most likely that you cannot deploy to iOS < 9 without an Apple account (i.e. $99/yr)

Answer (score 10):

Try to **reconnect your device** and wait for **copying symbolic files symbol**  to complete the process. I was getting **same error in Xcode 7.2.1 with iOS 9.2.1. on iPhone6**

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9.X is supported from Xcode 7 onwards. Please ensure you are using correct Xcode.

If you are using the right Xcode then check your hard disk. It should not be full. If so, delete some stuff and then retry.

Also, just a thought, I believe you tapped on "Trust" button when connected your device with your desktop.

You can take a look at the supported devices list here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

Comment: I just installed Xcode, so of course it is running the latest version. It is 7.0.1. I did press "Trust" as well. My disk has over 100GB left on it.